# default-libmysqlclient-dev or libperconaserverclient20-dev?

Tags: mysql, percona, libmysql, azerothcore

To compile AzerothCore, I need to install `default-libmysqlclient-dev` (it's `libmysqlclient-dev` for debian 9).

But since I use Percona instead of MySQL, I'm wondering if I should install `default-libmysqlclient-dev` or `libperconaserverclient20-dev`.

I couldn't find anything about a link/correlation between both. The only thing I've found is this quote:

> After installing default-libmysqlclient-dev (which conflicts with/replaces libperconaserverclient20-dev) indexer works fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [source](https://forums.percona.com/t/whats-the-difference-between-libperconaserverclient20-dev-and-libmysqlclient-dev/8968), unless you're using some specific feature to Percona, either `default-libmysqlclient-dev` (`libmysqlclient-dev`) or `libperconaserverclient20-dev` will work.